# What is the remainder produced when the integer $ 2099^{2017^{13164589}}$ is divided by $99$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'am looking for the remainder produced when the integer $2099^{2017^{13164589}}$ is divided by $99$ ? The goal reached is to avoid large integers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please share your thoughts so people can help you better.

Answer (score 5):

We know by [Euler's Totient Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) that $a^{\phi(99)}\equiv 1\mod 99$ for all $a$ with $\gcd(a,99)=1$ (so also for $a=2099$). So, the exponent works $\mod \phi(99)$, and $\phi(99)=60$, so we wish to compute $$2017^{13164589}\mod 60$$ We can again use the totient function to know that $a^{\phi(60)}\equiv a^{16}\equiv 1\mod 60$ - thus, we wish to compute $$13164589\mod 16$$ This is not too hard: this is $13$. Now we know $$2017^{13164589}\equiv 2017^{13}\equiv 37^{13}\mod 60$$ A little bit of trying and we see $37^4\equiv 1 \mod 60$ - giving us $$2017^{13164589}\equiv 37\mod 60$$ Thus we're left with $$2099^{2017^{13164589}}\equiv 2099^{37}\equiv 20^{37}\mod 99$$ This requires a bit of brute force to obtain $$2099^{2017^{13164589}}\equiv 92\mod 99$$ Still a computationally-heavy solution, but better than simply computing $2099^{2017^{13164589}}$.

Hope this helped!

Comment: If one works separately mod $9$ and mod $11$, the calculations can be done in one's head.

Comment: Same principles as in the nicely written answer above that works mod $99$. For example, $2099\equiv 2\pmod{9}$ and $2017\equiv 1\pmod{6}$ so the whole ugly exponent is congruent to $1$ mod $6$, and therefore our number is congruent to $2$ mod $9$. Mod $11$ is a little more work, but not much.

Answer (score 1):

We'll use the fact $a^k\equiv a^{k\mod\phi(n)}\mod n$ where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function. This congruence follows from $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\mod n$.

$\phi(9)=6$ and $\phi(6)=2$. 
$$
2017^{13164589}\equiv2017^{13164589\mod\phi(6)}\equiv2017^{13164589\mod 2}\equiv 2017^1\equiv1\mod 6\\
2099^{2017^{13164589}}\equiv2099^{2017^{13164589}\mod \phi(9)}\equiv2099^{2017^{13164589}\mod 6}\equiv2099^1\equiv2\mod 9
$$
$\phi(11)=10$ and $\phi(10)=4$.
$$
2017^{13164589}\equiv2017^{13164589\mod 4}\equiv 2017^{9\mod 4}\equiv2017^1\equiv 7\mod 10\\
2099^{2017^{13164589}}\equiv2099^{2017^{13164589}\mod 10}\equiv2099^7\equiv9^7\equiv(-2)^7\equiv-128\equiv-7\equiv4\mod 11
$$
Now consider the set of congruences
$$
x\equiv2\mod 9,\quad x\equiv4\mod 11\cdots(1)
$$
$x=9a+11b$ for some $a,b$. $(a,b)=(9,1)$ makes sure the previous congruences in $(1)$ are satisfied. So one solution to $(1)$ is $92$. As $gcd(9,11)=1$, by Chinese Remainder theorem
$$
2099^{2017^{13164589}}\equiv 92\mod(9\cdot11=99)
$$
as $2099^{2017^{13164589}}$ is also a solution to $(1)$.